# WebView doesn't display images and play js

Tags: android, webview

I got the simplest job on Upwork, but was fckd

There is a [site](http://onlinegamesreview.online/landing.php?matic=31&jesee=14) and I just have to wrap it with my app, but top buttons don't work (js problem), and images empty, my chrome android browser do it well. I was googling as mad, but the resolution was not found. Now the job is not mine, but I still want to understand what is wrong.

here is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    webView.settings.apply {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
    }

    webView.loadUrl("http://onlinegamesreview.online/")
}
```

I have tried many things I have found and it will be better if you will show me a real working code, instead of instructions

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDB2F.png)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I have added Internet Permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private static final String TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_URL = "http://onlinegamesreview.online/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl(TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_URL);
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressDialog.setMessage("loading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            showDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_URL);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            hideDialog();
        }
    }

    private void hideDialog() {

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void showDialog() {

        if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Obtained Output]

Comment: I am trying your code.I will get back to you shortly @VeeronTen

Comment: I was able to load the images @VeeronTen

Comment: what... Can you provide a screenshot? mb it is a problem with my phone?..

Comment: what do you think is a problem?

Comment: also what is "My Browser"?

Comment: I thought its an Internet problem (I though you didn't add it in manifest) at first and also there might be few errors in loading the URL .MyBrowser is the snippet where we load the webview and get having callbacks when the Url has been loaded in the webview.It is extending the webview having callbacks of loading the data.

Comment: Can you see screenshot now?

Comment: still does not work for me. a have permission too. weird

Comment: Have you tried the output in any other mobile? Just for verification.

Comment: I am able to see the output in the emulator as well @VeeronTen.

Comment: that is working with emulator, problem with my phone. well, i will be more wise next time. ty for your time and have a good live.

Comment: @VeeronTen I'm glad you got the output. No need to say about wise because sometimes we check only in one physical device and we forget about testing in other devices. And I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Try these for images

```
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

> For Js

```
    WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: same result, mate

Comment: OK, try with a different device, with different android version and see if it is working. I tried in my device and it is working fine.